# SVG does not scale up again

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, responsive

Currently I'm making a band-site with HTML. My idea was to have a banner in the -tag where you can click on seperate members to go to there individual page, in an "about us"-page. The basics work, but I have 2 problems.

1. If I scale the page down the 's are responsive but if I scale up they aren't anymore.
2. The whole SVG works only on my laptop on any other device it does not work at all.

How can I fix this?

This is the, relevant, code I have right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
html{
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#F1F1F1;
    color:#212121;
    font-size:1.0875vw;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1150px){
    html{
        font-size:12.50625px;
    }
}
body{
    margin:0px;
}
.afbeelding_container{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
.afbeelding_container .tekst_container{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.svg_container{
    position:absolute;
    top:0.625em;
    left:1.25em;
}
.MenuButton{
    font-size:38px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#F1F1F1;
    float:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width:441.92px) {
    .MenuButton {
        font-size:8.2vw;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav style="width:100%">
        <div style="width:100%" class="afbeelding_container">
            <img src="Afbeeldingen/Jeopardy Banner 1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="svg_container">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1600 460">
                    <g class="hover_group" opacity="0">
                        <a href="maudn.html">
                            <rect x="195.2" y="54.4" width="228.8" height="405.3" opacity="0.2" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        </a>
                    </g>
                    <g class="hover_group" opacity="0">                         
                        <a href="maudj.html">
                            <rect x="448" y="54.4" width="214.4" height="405.3" opacity="0.2" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        </a>
                    </g>                                
                    <g class="hover_group" opacity="0">                         
                        <a href="bjorn.html">
                            <rect x="691.2" y="54.4" width="234.56" height="405.3" opacity="0.2" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        </a>
                    </g>                                
                    <g class="hover_group" opacity="0">                         
                        <a href="anne.html">
                            <rect x="960" y="54.4" width="200" height="405.3" opacity="0.2" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        </a>
                    </g>                                
                    <g class="hover_group" opacity="0">                         
                        <a href="merwin.html">
                            <rect x="1174.4" y="54.4" width="219.52" height="405.3" opacity="0.2" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        </a>
                    </g>                                                            
                        <a href="https://www.sophiebik.nl">
                            <rect x="0" y="403" width="100" height="56" style="fill:blue;fill-opacity:0"/>
                        </a>                                
                </svg>
                    <div class="tekst_container">
                        <p><div id="myNav" class="overlay">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                            <div class="overlay-content" style="margin-left:1.vw">
                                <a href="index.html" >Home</a>
                                <a href="over_ons.html">Over ons</a>
                                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="MenuButton" id="MenuButton" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
                            <script>
                                function openNav() {
                                document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
                                document.getElementById("MenuButton").style.color = "#222";
                                }
                                function closeNav() {
                                document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
                                document.getElementById("MenuButton").style.color = "#F1F1F1";
                                }
                            </script>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your svg tag is missing some essential features, like `width`, `height` and `xmlns` for a browser to interpret it correctly. You might want to include at least these: `width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

Comment: I've add them and my desktop reveals the SVG now but way smaller and not in place in comparison to my laptop. And still it's not responsive by scaling up. Are there other options?

Comment: Give your SVG container a width, as the SVG will otherwise just scale down. I feel like this might be overcomplicated with an SVG just for hovering elements... Why not just use the image of your band stretching a relative container to 100%, then place boxes with sizes and positions defined by `%`? This will give you the same effect in a much leaner form. I feel SVG is overkill here since you hide _all_ of it. This makes things complicated in a way it shouldnt be.

Comment: Like this way the size scales but the positioning doesn't, but I feel I'm doing something wrong in the percentage?<div class="afbeelding_container" style="position:relative" width="100%">
    <img src="Afbeeldingen/Jeopardy Banner 1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="tekst_container">
   <div style="background-color:red;color:red;width:14.3vw;height:25vw;margin-left:46%;margin-top:11.5%"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

Comment: I would also make my sizes in %, since that will ensure they are all based on the size of your container box,  so if you ever limit or change the size of your container, you inner boxes will scale appropriately.

Comment: With percentages instead of vw's in the height and width there is no box at all. Can you send a code of such a box, please? 'Cause I'm stuck on that part.

Comment: I have posted an answer with an example of how to make such scaling boxes on top of an image that is used to define the height of your container. Have a look, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest abandoning your plan of using a scalable SVG for this and simple allow the box to be sized by your images, and place boxes inside it absolute to align with the image position. The below example is very simple, and once you have your percentage locations and widths, the example will scale up and down perfectly:

```css
header {
  
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  
}

header img {
  
  width: 100%;
  
}

header a {
  
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
}

header a#member1 {
  
  width: 23%;
  height: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 13%;
  
}

header a#member2 {
  
  width: 13%;
  height: 55%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 43%;
  
}

header a#member3 {
  
  width: 33%;
  height: 15%;
  top: 35%;
  left: 65%;
  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/900x300" />
  <a href="#" id="member1">Band Member 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="member2">Band Member 2</a>
  <a href="#" id="member3">Band Member 3</a>
</header>
```

Keep in mind all my values are really just examples, as I have no idea what your actual desired result should look like.

Comment: That works almost. On the picture, the members are standing on the bottom so the boxes do also have. I did this and the boxes floated through the bottom-end of the picture when I scaled the window down. [nav a#member1 { 
  width: 14.1%;
  height: 84.5%;
  top: 14%;
  left: 13.2%;  
}] This are the percentages of that member. Is there something wrong in them?

Comment: I cant really say, be sure there are no max values applied to anything of the wrapper, and your values dont add up to over 100%,  also, dont use margins etc... i cannot see a way this could fail if your numbers are correct...

Comment: That's allright. This is good enough, movement is only obvious visible with a device-width equal to phone where you can't hover so don't see the boxes. I can go further with this, thanks a lot! :)